# How to resolve "Interface is not visible from class loader" in Java

Tags: java, web, soap, classloader

I have been trying to use GBGId3Global Web service (SOAP based) for KYC&AML using Java (Spring). But my app is throwing ***"Interface com.id3global.IGlobalCredentials is not visible from class loader"*** exception. IGlobalCredentials is the library interface provided from GBG. I put this lib in my classpath (very messy organization of code, they put over 700 class/interfaces in one package):

```
src/main/java/
    /com/id3global
    /my_app_package/sub_packages
```

I did search and [found similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211176/interface-is-not-visible-from-classloader-when-using-a-proxy) (but very limited) answers which I could not find sufficient answer. Hence, I decided to give it as a general question. In which cases, this exception is thrown and how to resolve it in the context of web applications

**EDIT:
Sorry, I forgot to mention one important thing, I am behind corporate proxy. But the requested host is open. And this is the [WSDL URL](https://id3global.com/ID3gWS/ID3global.svc?wsdl)**

**EDIT-II**: I was running the project from eclipse directly, but then tried from the command line:

```
java -jar project.jar
```

And it is working without problem, what might be the case for this behavior?