# interface com.cadence.javademo.workflows.HelloWorldWorkflow is not visible from class loader

Tags: java, spring-boot, cadence-workflow

I am new to CadenceWorkflow and I am implementing Hello world web application using Spring Boot.
Also gone through [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211176/interface-is-not-visible-from-classloader-when-using-a-proxy) but couldn't figure how to solve.

Refer below code

```java
Worker.Factory f= new Worker.Factory(new WorkflowServiceTChannel("##.##.##.##", ##),"sample-domain");  
Worker worker = f.newWorker("TestWorker"); // adds taskList  
worker.registerWorkflowImplementationTypes(HelloWorldWorkflowImpl.class);  

WorkflowClient workflowClient = WorkflowClient.newInstance("##.##.##.##", ##),"sample-domain");  
HelloWorldWorkflow flow = workflowClient.newWorkflowStub(HelloWorldWorkflow.class);   
flow.getGreetings("Max");
```